# Speeding up a looked call to requests.post()

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a function that builds several hundred json requests objects and stores them in a list, I then loop through this list to send all these requests to their destination URL, one at a time. This process takes 10-15 minutes to complete.

Is there any alternative approach which would speed this up?

Here is my loop:

```
for x in range(0,len(request_payload)-1):
    # format the request as json
    data = json.dumps(request_payload[x])
    # send the request
    requests.post(url='https://URL_REMOVED/conversion', data=data, headers=headers)
```

Comment: you could use async so they don't have to go one at a time

Comment: ...or threading. Personally I've always used threading for this kind of thing, but asyncio is another very popular module.

Comment: @SuperStew I've not used either of these before, do you have any code examples of how one would implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some partially written code to give you the idea. You need to define a function that does what you want, then start a number of threads that run that function. The only complication is you need to split your inputs up so each thread handles a subset of your inputs. I've used a neat little trick which I've used before to generate unique slices of your input list for each thread. Apologies if there are any typos as I typed this out from memory with no testing.

Technically you don't need the t.join part in this example, but it's good to understand how to join threads (i.e. wait for them to finish).

```
from threading import Thread

def make_requests(list_of_requests):
    #your requests code here

threads=[]
num_threads = 10
for i in range(num_threads):
    threads.append(Thread(target=make_requests, args=(all_requests[i::num_threads],)))
    threads[i].start()

# block until all threads are done
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

This will make your code faster because you will have multiple requests running in parallel - for example if the site takes 5 seconds to respond to each request, ten requests would take 50 seconds (plus a tiny amount for your code itself). Now it will take 5 seconds, plus a slightly larger tiny bit of time for your threaded code. When you have code that spends a long time waiting for IO, threading is often a good choice.

Comment: Thanks Simon - so am I building `make_requests()` to send a single request, then using it in a loop below? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: `make_requests` should take a list of requests and then execute them all. I've made an edit to the code to make it less ambiguous. The slice `all_requests[i::num_threads]` means that each version of `make_requests` will receive a different list. `all_requests` should be your master list of everything you want done.

Comment: Sorry, typo. It's should be `threads[i]`. The idea is you are starting the `Thread` object that you just added to the `threads` list.

Comment: Thanks, I am still getting `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` for `threads[i].start()` - it looks okay to me, what am I missing?

Comment: I missed a close-bracket off the end of the previous line so if you've copied it that might be the issue.

Comment: Great - many thanks for your help, great to learn something new!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206364/discussion-between-ben-p-and-simonn).